# My conditional isn't working, i'm a beginner programmer

Tags: java, operators, conditional-statements

```
double a = 10;// the 10 dollars to spend
double b = 0;// the cost of he food
double c;// final total
double d;// amount of sandwiches
c = a-b;
String Order;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

And here is what i'm trying to do my objective is to get the number of sandwiches and multiply it; while the number is 2 or lower she says one thing 3 or higher another. The problem is it's asking  me to initialize the variable to 0 but obviously d*0 is still zero.

```
System.out.println("That'll be 1.06 how many would you like?");
b = 1.06*d;
d = sc.nextDouble();
System.out.println(d <= 2 ?"Ok! Coming right up Sir!":"...Ok.... she     probably thinks you're a fatso now.");
System.out.println("She hands you back "+(a-b)+" as your change");
break;
```

Comment: I know this is an example question but give your variables some meaningful names to go along with the comments.. maybe instead of b, you can do (double cost;)

Comment: why do you first try to calculate sum and only then ask how many burgers? In real world we do vice versa usually

Comment: I used to teach programming to newbies. One basic idea I had to get across is, even though computers are so fast that they seem to do everything at once, they don't. They do the steps in order, one at a time, and they have to complete each one before they can start the next one. Also, they don't know what you want to do. They just do what they are told, even if you are not sure what to tell them to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
System.out.println("That'll be 1.06 how many would you like?");
b = 1.06*d;
d = sc.nextDouble();
```

You haven't initialized `d`, so when you do your multiplication you are multiplying nothing. You need to load the scanner's value into `d` before you multiply `b`.

```
System.out.println("That'll be 1.06 how many would you like?");
d = sc.nextDouble();
b = 1.06*d;
```

Comment: No worries. Be sure to select a post which answered your question to reward the answerers.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the order of your assignments.

```
b = 1.06*d; // <-- what's d?
d = sc.nextDouble();
```

like

```
d = sc.nextDouble();
b = 1.06 * d;
```

Also, you should pick more meaningful variable names.